# Compute the probability density function of $Y$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda = 4$, and let $Y$ be the random variable defined by $Y = 7 e^X$. Compute the probability density function of $Y$

A little lost on how to begin this one, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We can use the method of transformations. I prefer to calculate, or start to calculate, the cdf of $Y$. For $y\gt 7$ we have
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(7e^X\le y)=\Pr(X\le \ln(y/7))=1-e^{-4\ln(y/7)}.$$
Simplify, and differentiate to find the density function.